# How do I change iTunes Wi-Fi Synch Settings

Tags: itunes, wifi, data-synchronization, settings

I need to change the Wi-Fi Synch settings to synch with my new laptop.  My iPhone was originally set up to synch with a different laptop.   How do I change the settings on the phone to synch with my laptop at home.    The last time it was synched was Feb 2013

Answer (score 1):

Is your iPhone setup in the new laptop's iTunes ?? If it is, then it should be this iTunes library it will use.